# Why would anyone want to use the pass power Exp. Point Power ↓?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I can definitely understand the rationale for Exp. Point Power ↑, but don't understand why someone would want to prevent their Pokemon from gaining experience.

Comment: Some competitive players like to keep their pokemon at level 50 or 60 for certain tournaments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall, the Level of your pokemon cannot exceed certain limits until you have earned certain badges.
Most of the times your traded pokemon out-level all the others on your roster. It is sometimes useful to limit their growth so that they dont go above their obedience limit.

Comment: only traded pokemon don't obey after certain levels without the required badges. If you are the original trainer (the one that caught it, trading back and forth doesn't matter) it will obey no matter what.

Comment: Ah yes, how could I forget!

Comment: @Kevin - http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Obedience   Just found this. You are right.